# How do I escape nested {} for format purposes?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting, escaping

I have the following string I need to format:

```
header = """
   class SP{
       function A{
           return {}
       }
"""
print(header.format('some_value;'))
```

What I try to print is:

```
class SP{
    function A{
         return some_value;
    }
```

How do I escape the outer {} **NOTICE THE IMBALANCED curly brackets**

Comment: `{{ ... }}`.....

Comment: and if I have unbalanced curly brackets? like { {   {this are for format} }

Comment: It still works: `{{  {{ {...} }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header = """
   class SP{{
       return {0}
   }};
"""
print(header.format('some_value;'))
```